# Solving and plotting a non-linear and polynomial equations of degree 3 and higher

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, polynomials

I'm doing the following and cannot plot the function, could anyone spot a problem please

```
0<=a<=1 ; 0 <= ρ <= 1; 0 <= b <= 3

eq = 0.1 (20 - 70 a) + (1 - ρ)^(-1-b) . ρ . (2 - 2 ρ + b ρ)==0;

soln = Solve[eq && 0 <= ρ <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 1, ρ, Reals];

Plot3D[Solve[eq && 0 <= ρ <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= a <= 1, ρ, Reals],
  {b, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0.2, 1}, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] &
  /@ {"b", "a", "ρ"}), ColorFunction -> Automatic]
```

Thanks

Comment: There are numerous syntax errors. After that, b seems to be Real, is not it?   If yes, is not the equation of degree 3, but the transcendental one. As a rule it then cannot be solved by `Solve `.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Yes b is real. So how can i solve/plot it then?

Comment: You might succeed with a numerical approach, say, with `FindRoot`. But you need first to fix all syntatic errors. They are much too many to point out each.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch thanks for your reply. My main aim is to plot a graph of with respect to different values of b and a. do you think FindRoot would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Alexei Boukbitch, `Solve` cannot solve `eq` for `ρ`.  Although `FindRoot` can obtain numerical solutions, a more straightforward to obtain the desired plot is to use `Solve` to obtain `a` instead, which then can be plotted.  With extraneous code eliminated,

```
eq = (2 - 7 a) + (1 - ρ)^(-1 - b) ρ (2 - 2 ρ + b ρ) == 0;
soln = First@ Solve[eq, a];
Plot3D[a /. soln, {b, 0, 1}, {ρ, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"b", "ρ", "a"})]
```

[image]

Incidentally, an alternative way to plot the desired surface that has `ρ` more obviously the third dimension is

```
ParametricPlot3D[{a /. soln, b, ρ}, {b, 0, 1}, {ρ, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] &   /@ {"a", "b", "ρ"})]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

In answer to a question posed by Saman in a comment below, `ρ = 0` can be plotted for `a < 2/7` as follows.

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{a /. soln, b, ρ}, {b, 0, 3}, {ρ, 0, 1}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}, {0, 1}}, 
       AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"a", "b", "ρ"})], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, 2/7}, {b, 0, 3}]]
```

[image]

Note that the range of `b` has been increased to `{0, 3}`, also at the request of Salam.

Comment: thanks for your answer. however when I change the interval of "b" to  0<= b<=3 the plot wont change (does not calculate for b>=1 ). Also is there any way to show in the plot that for low value of "a" (e.g. a< 0.3) ρ become flat in the graph. just to show for  a< 0.3  ρ is always 0.

Comment: The range of `b` actually does increase to `0<= b<=3` for `Plot3D`.  To achieve the same for `ParametricPlot3D`, use `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}, {0, 1}}`.  I do not believe it is true that for `a< 0.3`, `ρ` is always `0`.  Actually, for `a<2/7`, `ρ<0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes you are right! but what I meant was because ρ is bounded between 0 and 1 i want to show in the graph that for all ρ<0  we should have ρ=0 (instead of having it blank in the graph). Also could you guide me how to plot a function with the values ρ that I get from solving the eq. (e.g. I have another function of ρ and I want to see how that function behave with respect to the value of ρ that I already got). Sorry about these questions i'm new to the mathematica and I'm learning it. and thanks again for your help.

Comment: See the Addendum to my Answer for the first part of your last Comment.  You can plot a second expression for `ρ` superimposed on any of the plots in my Answer in  much the same way as I added the `ρ = 0` plot.  For further discussion on this last item, you may wish to search Mathematica.StackExchange or ask another Question